# What does randomly colored availability bar mean?

Tags: utorrent

I noticed that a certain torrent, which was the last one in the torrent list, had a strangely colored availability bar. After exceeding the magical number 256, the bar weirds out. Color of the bar changed each time the last torrent was selected. I grabbed a number of screenshots from which I cut only the rightmost fragment of it along with the current availability index:

[image]

The whole bar became a solid color, which didn't seem to be the average color of the whole bar. Pink, light-green and turquoise  were prevalent, with much rarer brownish-tan and purple. Yellow only seems to occur right after the index becomes greater than 256. The weird thing is this persisted even after reloading uTorrent application and rebooting the PC. After the download completed, availability index lowered to 14 and the bar returned to normal. Naturally, I wanted to check things out again, so I deleted data and re-downloaded the torrent to see if this keeps happening. It does.

Is this a bug or an intended feature? If so, what do these colors signify?

Comment: I'm not sure about the colors, but the availability number itself apparently refers to the number of copies of the file that are available on the network: http://help.utorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/164808